# Python Selenium Web Scrape embedded csv/excel file in XPATH to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, selenium, download, webdriver

I am working on a Python requirement to download data from a secured website using Python Selenium WebDriver. I am using `xpath.click()` to download the file to a local download folder or any specific folder I wanted to.

Instead of downloading to a folder, I wanted to load to a database table.

I am looking for help to know how I can direct the downloaded file to a table.

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modules--reports-gridTar-instanceGrid"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a').click()
print(data) // output: None
```

The downloaded file is seen on the web browser:

[image]

Not sure how could I pick that file showing on the browser to a table?

Answer (score 0):

don't `click()` but get `href` attribute to download with python.

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modules--reports-gridTar-instanceGrid"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a')
url = data.get_attribute('href')
req = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
response = req.read()
print(response)
```

Comment: I did try using the get_attribute('href') and got the URL which holds the csv file. By opening and reading that url throws some scripts like this .....b'<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="position:inherit;">\r\n\t<head id="ctl00_ctl00_Head1"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM|.......not able to read the actual csv file

Comment: try add referrer header in your request or also add cookies